# How to send parameters to server Using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I am using `NSURLSession` for integrating services

When I send request to server below "first Request" formate response coming from server

And when I send "second Request" formate response not coming from server

What mistake I have done below "second Request" format please help me

```
NSString *usernameString = usernameTxt.text;
NSString *passwordString = passwordTxt.text;
NSString *Grant_type = @"password";
NSString *Finalstr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@UserName%@Password%@grant_type", usernameString,passwordString,Grant_type];

NSString * finalString = @"UserName=10122951&Password=123456&grant_type=password";
```

First Request:

```
[post5 postServieCalling:@"%@myURl here" : finalString];
```

Second Request:

```
[post5 postServieCalling:@"%@myURl here" : Finalstr];
```

Comment: there is no problem i f send request like above first Formate'

Comment: problem is coming only when i send second request formate i think there is i have done mistack or other wise there is no problem from server side background class

Comment: if i send  NSString * finalString = @"UserName=10122951&Password=123456&grant_type=password";

Comment: then no problem is coming

Comment: NSString *usernameString = usernameTxt.text;
        NSString *passwordString = passwordTxt.text;
        NSString *Grant_type = @"password";
        NSString *Finalstr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@UserName%@Password%@grant_type", usernameString,passwordString,Grant_type]; when i send this formate problem is coming

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UserName=%@&Password=%@&grant_type=%@", usernameString,passwordString,Grant_type]

Comment: ok i will try and meet u again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104151/discussion-between-kirit-modi-and-abhiram).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104153/discussion-between-kirit-modi-and-abhiram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *Finalstr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@UserName%@Password%@grant_type", usernameString,passwordString,Grant_type];
```

Replace with below code.

```
 NSString *Finalstr = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UserName=%@&Password=%@&grant_type=%@", usernameString,passwordString,Grant_type]
```